# C# Parse data and put into correct data type

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently trying to read in from a file and put the data into the right spot in the data. However I am finding that parsing a string in C# is a lot more difficult than c++. An example from the file that I am reading in is as follows:

CGI HOLDING CORP THK 2.15 0.01  0.47 -64.17 6.25 1.92 23.78

into the following data type

```
public class StockInfo
    {
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string TickerSymbol { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceChange { get; set; }
        public decimal PercentChange { get; set; }
        public decimal YTDChange { get; set; }
        public decimal FiftyTwoWeekHigh { get; set; }
        public decimal FiftyTwoWeekLow { get; set; }
        public decimal PE_Ratio { get; set; }
    }
```

So Company would = "CGI HOLDING CORP"

Ticker Symbol = "THK"

Current price = 2.15 etc...

However I can't figure out how to parse the data correctly. I have tried using a regular expression but the Name can have different amount of words in it and need to sperate it from the ticker.

Ex: CHICAGO MERCANTILE EX HD CME 301.13 23.53  8.48 31.67 315.00 132.57 35.73

any ideas that can point me in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: is it possible to separate each value by comma(,) or some other characters ?

Comment: Nope, they are as is unfortunately. Otherwise I could just split the string on comma(,). I'm thinking a regex reading from right to left might be my best option.

Comment: if number of fields to parse is fixed, and there's no optional field in the input, can pass backward from the end of the string. After parsing 7 decimal, next one is ticker symbol, the rest is the name

Comment: is Ticker Symbol "THK" a static word ?

Comment: Isn't space a delimiter here?

Answer (score 1):

I have created an simple Program for you, it may be not the best way, but I think it will bring you to your destination.

```
  string input = "CGI HOLDING CORP THK 2.15 0.01 0.47 -64.17 6.25 1.92 23.78";
  List<string> inputSplit = input.Split(' ').ToList();

  PE_Ratio = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count-1]);
  FiftyTwoWeekLow = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 2]);
  FiftyTwoWeekHigh = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 3]);
  YTDChange = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 4]);
  PercentChange = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 5]);
  PriceChange = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 6]);
  CurrentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 7]);
  TickerSymbol = inputSplit[inputSplit.Count - 8];

  for (int i = 0; i < inputSplit.Count - 8; i++)
  {
    Company = Company + (inputSplit[i] + " ");
  }

  Company = Company.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna go for a regex, you can use:

```
(.+)(\w{3})((?:\s\-?\d{1,3}\.\d{2}){7})
```

This matches and groups both your examples. The company name will have a trailing whitespace, as well as the "number group" will have a leading whitespace, but this shouldn't be a problem to eliminate this in your code.

[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM8aP9/1)

Explanation, from right to left:

```
((?:\s\-?\d{1,3}\.\d{2}){7})
```

Matches seven times the (non-capturing) group `(?:\s\-?\d{1,3}\.\d{2})` while this in turn matches on: a whitespace (`\s`) followed by an optional dash (`\-?`) followed by one to three numbers (`\d{1,3}`) followed by a dot (`\.`) followed by two numbers (`\d{2}`). So this matches the seven numbers at the end of your input.

```
(\w{3})
```

Matches the three-character 'ticker symbol'.

```
(.+)
```

Matches all the rest: the company name in your example.